# Trigger API Call for incoming emails

Tags: power-automate

I need to set up a workflow that triggers an API call to an external URL when an email is received on my Outlook 365 inbox. This API call will contain data parsed from the sender email/content. Which connector should be used to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up a workflow with at least or just two elements:

1. `When a new email arrives` trigger from `Office 365 Outlook` group
2. `HTTP` action to invoke your API

Comment: How do I do this without paying for the premium HTTP power automate action?